# Delete rows with equal and consecutive values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Consider this table

```
var1    var2        var3
565 P0049129/21     146
565 P0020151/04     146
```

I would like to go over this table, find consecutive lines where var3 equals the same value (146 in this example) and remove one of those lines.

Note that in this table there are other rows where var3=146 and I want to keep those rows. I just want to remove duplication when var3 has the same value on two consecutive rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[rowid(rleid(var3)) == 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` and then `duplicated`.

```
df[!duplicated(data.table::rleid(df$var3)), ]
```

This will keep only the first row of consecutive values and delete the rest.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` to find the groups that are same

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[,  .I[1],rleid(var3)]$V1
df1[i1]
#     var1        var2 var3
#@1:  565 P0049129/21  146
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(var3 != lag(var3, default = first(var3)))) %>%
   slice(1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   var1 var2   var3
#  <int> <chr>       <int>
#1   565 P0049129/21   146
```

---

Or we can do this in. `base R`

```
grp <- with(rle(df$var3), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
subset(df, !duplicated(grp))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(565L, 565L), var2 = c("P0049129/21", 
"P0020151/04"), var3 = c(146L, 146L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```